# Fragment getActivity() vs Interface Callbacks?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I was wondering if calling Activity methods with its reference via getActivity() in Fragment is legit way instead using Interface callback methods.

Interfaces helps to follow Design Patterns.
But, Sometimes when i am in hurry i use getActivity() am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. It is just another way of doing it. But using interfaces has it's own advantages such as reusing the fragments in different activities. You can follow discussion on this link for clarification
http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/